# What is a good design pattern to avoid having to use a global variable at the top your main form?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Every time I talk to experienced programmers, they talk about having global variables being a bad practice because of debugging or security exploits. I have a simple List of strings I want to load from a a textfile and access across different methods in my form. Before, I would simply initialize said variable at the top, inside of my form class and use it across methods. I always try to reduce that practice when I can and only initialize those variables when I really need them. Is it a bad practice to do this or do more experienced programmers do this too? Is there a standard design pattern method of doing this so you don't have to use "global variables" at the top of your form?

Comment: It's only bad practice if used for passing values that should/could be parameters.  Use private/internal to restrict the scope of where such variables can be used.  As to debugging, there is no issue.  (Only bad programmers say all globals are bad.)

Comment: If that list is a field inside your form - it is not really a global variable.

Comment: I think it is better to create a class to get the data from the text file and expose a list that is used in multiple forms.

Comment: There is a good chance you are using "global" as synonym of "instance" rather than more common "static". This is reasonable as C# does not define concept of "global variable". Consider showing examples of what you believe is bad practice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you're talking about C# and it's a fully-object-oriented programming language, there's no way to declare *global variables*.

In an OOP language like C#, a **bad** practice can be simulating *global variables* using *static classes*:

```
public static class Global
{
     public static string Value1 { get; set; }
     public static int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

...to later get or set these values from other classes. Definitely, this a bad practice because state should be held by specific and meaningful objects.

Usually, in a perfect/ideal OOP solution, you should pass such values from class to class using constructors:

```
public class X
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Y y = new Y(this);
        y.DoChildStuff();
    }
}

public class Y
{
    public class Y(X parent)
    {
         Parent = parent;
    }

    public X Parent { get; }

    public void DoChildStuff()
    {
         // Do some stuff with Parent
    }
}
```

Or also, you might pass states providing arguments to some method:

```
public class Y
{    
    public void DoChildStuff(X parent)
    {
         // Do some stuff with "parent"
    }
}
```

Since you're passing states with *reference types*, if any of the methods in the chain decide to change `Parent.Value1` with another value, all objects holding a reference to the same `X` object will get the new `X.Value1`.

Some fellows might argue that we usually build *configuration objects* which own a lot of properties accessed by other arbitrary objects, right? BTW, *configuration* is a *concept* per se, isn't it? And we usually categorize configuration values using composition:

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{
     public DatabaseConfiguration Database { get; } = new DatabaseConfiguration();
     public StorageConfiguration Storage { get; } = new StorageConfiguration();
}

public class DatabaseConfiguration
{
     public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class StorageConfiguration
{
     public string TemporalFileDirectoryPath { get; set; }
     public string BinaryDirectoryPath { get; set; }
}
```

So later we *inject*  the application configuration wherever we need it:

```
// Please note that it's a VERY hypothetical example, don't take
// it as an actual advise on how to implement a data mapper!!
public class DataMapper
{
     public DataMapper(ApplicationConfiguration appConfig)
     {
           AppConfig = appConfig;
     }

     public ApplicationConfiguration AppConfig { get; }
     private IDbConnection Connection { get; }

     public void Connect()
     {
           // We access the configured connection string
           // from the application configuration object
           Connection = new SqlConnection(AppConfig.Database.ConnectionString);
           Connection.Open();
     }
}
```

In summary, and since I love comparing real-world and programming use cases, imagine that you never clean your room and you would use a single box to store every tool you might need some day. One day you need a screwdriver from the whole box, and you know that's inside it... But you need to throw everything in the box to the ground and work out the mess prior to find the priceless screwdriver to complete some home task.

Or imagine that you've bought a toolbox to store your tools in order, and once you need a screwdriver, you know that's in the toolbox and in the section where you store your screwdrivers.

You know that the second approach is the most mind-friendly. That is, when you develop software, you need to design mind-friendly architectures rather than a big mess of unrelated data and behaviors working together.

Comment: And if a writer accidentally injects/instantiates a new configuration the whole thing falls down in an over complicated mess, whereas a simple static could never have that problem, and despite your one toolbox scenario is far cleaner than looking for a single item stored in one of a few hundred toolboxes each with only 1 or 2 items.   (Far more work, far more messy, far more prone to error.)

Comment: @Rob You're converting an exception into the rule. Your description is a *bug*, isn't it? You can't architect a solution based on "what if I do a mistake". If you do such mistake, fix it! That's all. And usually you're going to use an IoC/DI container, where you'll define that configuration once and it'll be automatically injected anywhere (i.e., it'll always be the same instance during the application life-cycle).

Comment: @Rob Also, when you *inject a configuration* you're free to set up that certain areas of your app may use different configurations. Imagine that situation where certain areas need to work with database A and others with B. With a static configuration this would be hard to implement, while an *injected configuration* makes life easier. What's a problem for you, it can be an advantage in some scenarios!

Comment: Somewhat OK, but I don't like blanket statements "use of static classes to simulate globals is bad practice,"   Replacing a static-globals with a 'meaningful objects' too often:1:extra layer of complication & more ways for things to go wrong, 2: for 1-time initialized state values too often lipstick on a pig (and 3: why not a 'meaningful static', even better a meaningful-readonly-static-global, for eg. temp files location).  Injecting configuration, oops, left testing code in my class where I accidentally instantiated another instance - unique strength of static values: there can be only 1.

Comment: >> You're converting an exception into the rule. Your description is a bug, isn't it?  Yep, a bug only made possible by your addition of an extra layer of complexity.  Just made everybody's job harder just to support a bad programmers myth.  (just like "guns are lethal for people who don't know how to use them." - most of the time OK, but sometimes becomes the very instrument of your own demise.)

Comment: @Rob About guns, since I live in Europe, usually you don't own guns... :P

Comment: @Rob About your concerns, I would say that when you develop software on top of concepts like DI and you consider *configuration* a component, I don't see the danger of instantiating a configuration class manually: it's simply getting of the rails. Imagine a dev team where everyone injects the configuration object and someone decides to instantiate it manually everywhere. Would this produced code be part of the code base? I doubt it, a code reviewer would talk to that *disruptive developer* to refactor the wrong code to follow project's conventions.

Comment: @Rob And about the extra layer of complexity... Where's the extra layer and the complexity? It's a very simple class that you inject when required instead of using a static class with a lot of unrelated properties.

Comment: @Rob And if you want a set once configuration, use *read-only* configuration properties like you would do with a static class.

Comment: @Rob Maybe you enjoy [this Q&A](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40313/is-a-single-config-object-a-bad-idea) where there're many users exposing their thoughts about our discussion.

Comment: many answers, personal preferences, swot ... lets leave it there, ... not the place to discuss.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Fantastic example and explanation. Really enjoyed this perspective, thanks. +1

Comment: @Rhurac Thank you for your comment! Happy to know it's given some insights on this topic.